# How do I get the returned entity from a entitydatasource binding to a detailsview?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I'm trying to grab the entity on the `Selected` event of the datasource like so

```
protected void edsRetailer_OnSelected(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Results == null) return;
    var list =  (IEnumerable<Retailer>) e.Results;
}
```

The cast fails with the following error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectView`1[CCBusiness.Retailer]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CCBusiness.Retailer]'
```

I tried casting it to an `ObjectView`, but the class doesn't seem to exist when I try to cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to cast `e.Results` to `ObjectView`, because that already is the return type. (Besides, `System.Data.Objects.ObjectView` is an internal class). But the point is that it implements `IEnumrable` (as part of `IBindingList`), not `IEnuerable<T>`.

The common way to convert a non-generic IEnumerable to a generic one is the [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var list =  e.Results.Cast<Retailer>();
```